# What expression is correct (in your mind vs with your mind)?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

- Expressions:

1) They count **with** their mind instead of using PC *(with their brain)*

2) They count **in** their mind instead of using PC *(with their brain)*

---

I surfed the internet to find some at least, similar expression but didn't succeed

---

- Question:

> What expression is right?

Comment: What are you trying to describe here? Silent mental counting, as opposed to counting aloud?

Comment: The idiom is "she added the numbers up *in her head*".

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think that the verb *to count* doesn't work well in the context of making mathematicalензщ calculations using your intellectual ability, in other words--solving math problems *mentally*. The process may also be reffered to as ["mental maths"](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/master-mental-maths) or [mental arithmetic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/mental-arithmetic) that is doing calculations **in** your mind, without writing down any numbers. If you google for "calculate mentally" or "mentally calculate", you'll find [lots of examples](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calculate+mentally%2Cmentally+calculate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalculate%20mentally%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmentally%20calculate%3B%2Cc0).

Also, see the [" in one's head"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_one%27s_head) phrase which in your case hits the bull's eye, as Tromano pointed out in his comment:

> He was great with math and could give you batting averages calculated
>   in his head. [(the source)](https://books.google.ru/books?id=5TWLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA17&dq=%22calculated+in+his+head%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy3YXZmanaAhUNKywKHfIXBtQ4ChDoAQhfMAc#v=onepage&q=%22calculated%20in%20his%20head%22&f=false)

Comment: I was counting the numbers up in my mind when the doorbell rang.

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression is "**to count in mind**":

- **They count in their minds** instead of using **the** PC. (**Correct**)

Here is a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20count%20in%20the%20head&oq=to%20count%20in%20the%20head&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=to%20count%20in%20*%20mind) with examples:

- Math Master will help you to learn **to count in your mind** quickly and without errors, develop abstract and logical thinking.
- ...ancient abacus method - the ability **to count large numbers in the mind** easily and quickly, which ensures a significant development of child's mental abilities.

Comment: "You cannot count with your mind" -- try counting without your mind.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree +1

Comment: I don't think the difference is that clear cut. If you can count with your fingers, why not count with your mind?

Comment: Of course, you can say: I was counting the numbers in my mind. But not with my mind. Jeepers creepers. Makes the mind sound like an appendage.